# Animation/Segue from ViewController to itself with different data - Swift

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, segue, viewcontroller

I do have DetailViewController with infos of a single object from an array. (eg. i have an array of cars and i want to display 1 car of the array on the detailViewController)

By swiping left/right, i want to view the next/previous car in the array.

So far, i've just changed the labels texts matching the current car object, but i want an animation on every swipe.

```
switch swipeGesture.direction {
        case UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.Left:
            if currentIndex < events.count-1 {
                currentIndex += 1
            }
        case UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.Right:
            if currentIndex != 0 {
                currentIndex -= 1
            }
        default:
            break
        }
```

So, what is the most efficient way to archive this goal?

Comment: you want to animate whole or only part of data?

Comment: good question. I think i want to animate the swipe of the whole ViewController though.

Comment: Then I suppose `UIPageViewController` is your best option. You will be using different instances of the same `viewController`.

Comment: Ok, got that now. What if i want to animate only parts of the data? (eg. just 2 labels)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use [UIPageViewController](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIPageViewControllerClassReferenceClassRef/).

Comment: I think you misunderstood me. I want to use always the same ViewController, just with other data.

Comment: Which animation do you want ?

Comment: What is wrong with UIPageViewController ? You can use your DetailViewController for each page you want to display.